"Permission denied" when using WebDAV mount as docker volume
I'm trying to use my host-mounted (via davfs2 utility) WebDAV storage  as docker volume, but somehow got Permission denied though all target and parent folders have 777 linux permissions
# ls -ld /mnt/yandex_webdav
drwxrwxrwx 4 root root 424 Jul 13 09:03 /mnt/yandex_webdav

# docker run -d --name labelstudio -v /mnt/yandex_webdav:/tmp/yandex_webdav heartexlabs/label-studio:latest

# docker exec -it labelstudio ls -la /tmp/yandex_webdav
ls: cannot open directory '/tmp/yandex_webdav': Permission denied

# docker exec -it labelstudio ls -ld /tmp/yandex_webdav
drwxrwxrwx 4 root root 424 Jul 13 09:03 /tmp/yandex_webdav

My host OS is Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS, docker version is 26.0.0
What could be wrong?

This solution involves running the Docker container as a user with the necessary permissions to access the mounted WebDAV volume. This can be achieved by using the USER instruction in the Dockerfile or specifying the user at runtime.
Assume we have a Docker user named docker and our WebDAV volume is mounted at /mnt/webdav

Change Ownership:
sudo chown -R docker:docker /mnt/webdav
Modify Dockerfile:

# Dockerfile
FROM your-base-image
# Assuming the user 'docker' exists in the base image
USER docker


Run Docker Container:
docker run --rm -it --user docker -v /mnt/webdav:/mnt/webdav your-image

Check this article and this journal

Perhaps you should try mounting the disk via a driver plugin?
https://github.com/fentas/docker-volume-davfs

rm -rf /mnt/yandex_webdev
podman volume create yandex_webdev
podman run -d -v yandex_webdev:/tmp/yandex_webdev --name webdev docker.io/heartexlabs/label-studio:latest tail -f /dev/null
podman ps -as
podman exec webdev ls -la /tmp

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Logging in as the root user and running the command without sudo might work.

When you encounter a "permission denied" error or a file is write-protected in the Linux Terminal, you can often resolve it by adding sudo (which stands for "super user do") before the command. This grants the command superuser (administrator) privileges. In your case, the command would be:
sudo docker run -d --name label-studio -v /mnt/yandex_webdav:/tmp/yandex_webdav heartexlabs/label-studio:latest

It likely wouldn't work in this case since the error is coming from within docker, and sudo won't persist into that command.

@long-blade, thank you for reply, but unfortunately using sudo didn't help. Any other ideas ?
